# Why does Bitlocker intermittently require SQL service restart after sleep?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, encryption

I have a development machine that has two drives:

```
C:\ - Operating system (Win 10 Ent) and SQL Server 2012 Standard installation
D:\ - SQL Server databases, backups, logs
```

I recently activated [BitLocker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/bitlocker/bitlocker-overview) on both drives, then activated auto-unlock because I realised that SQL Server can't access the databases unless the drive is unlocked.

Now with SQL (and only SQL, all other services/programs are fine), on an **intermittent** basis I see the following behaviours occur:

1. After waking from sleep mode, and then starting SSMS, I cannot log in (login fails with invalid credentials error).  This occurs for the Windows login account only
2. If login succeeds, or if I login using the **sa** account, then all databases are in the `Pending Restore` state

I guess both of these are due to the drive becoming locked during sleep (or perhaps not?)?    After waking from sleep, if I restart the SQL Server service, and then restart SSMS, everything works fine.

I wondered what might cause this to be intermittent please, or if my assumptions are wrong, what is actually causing this?

*PS. Perhaps a BitLocker tag might be useful, as I see there are plenty of other questions relating to this???*

Comment: For anyone else finding this, I opened a Connect bug, not that anyone at Microsoft seems interested in feedback any more... https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3138250

Answer (score 0):

If somebody have the same problem:
Open Services and change Startup type from "Automatic" to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" and be happy.
And one more... you should delete password for bitlocker on drive D

Comment: Tried that already thanks but it didn't work.  Strangely, Win 11 on the exact same box doesn't suffer the same issue.